# How to make a query SPARQL multiline in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sparql, semantic-web

how to make a query SPARQL multiline in javascript? What is the correct syntax?

```
var query = "
    PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
    PREFIX fabio: <http://purl.org/spar/fabio/>
    PREFIX frbr: <http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/core#>

    SELECT DISTINCT ?x
    WHERE {
       ?x a fabio:Item.
    }";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are:

- Using the [string concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_())
- Using [ES6 multiline strings](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/template-strings/) along with a pre-processor like [Babel](http://babeljs.io)
- Using backslash to [escape](https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings) the new line character at the end
- Use a hack like [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/multiline) that reads function body as a string and extracts its contents.